# How to generate matrix from dynamic multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array as below where cid as an option and values are defined as its attributes. Such array is generating based on selection from O1, O2, O3 and so on.

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array 
    (
        [cid] => O1
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => O1A1
                [1] => O1A2
            )
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [cid] => O2
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => O2A1
                [1] => O2A2
                [2] => O2A3
            )
    )

)
```

Now I need to generate a matrix in HTML table as below:

```
        +--------+------------+-----------------------------+
        |   O1   |     O2     | Some other columns          |
        +--------+------------+-----------------------------+ 
        |  O1A1  |    O2A1    | Some other column values    |
        |  O1A1  |    O2A2    | Some other column values    |
        |  O1A1  |    O2A3    | Some other column values    |
        |  O1A2  |    O2A1    | Some other column values    |
        |  O1A2  |    O2A2    | Some other column values    |
        |  O1A2  |    O2A3    | Some other column values    |
        +--------+------------+-----------------------------+
```

There are total 6 rows ( creating like 2 X 3 (option O1 and O2 values)).  I have tried with nested for..loop but array have dynamic values ( it is based on selection).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :)

```
    <?php 
    $input = array(0 => array('cid' => 'O1', 'values' => array (0 => 'O1A1',1 => 'O1A2')), 1 => array('cid' => 'O2', 'values' => array (0 => 'O2A1', 1 => 'O2A2', 2=>'O2A3')));

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($input);

     ///make an array of matrix

    $matrixArr =array();

    for( $i= 0; $i< 2; $i++ ) 
    {
        for( $j=0; $j <3; $j++ ) 
        {
            $matrixArr[$input[0]['values'][$i]][]= $input[1]['values'][$j];
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($matrixArr);

    ///now print that array

    foreach($matrixArr as $key =>$val)
    {
        foreach($val as $v)
        {
            echo $key." | ".$v.' |  Some other column values </br>';
        }

    ?>
```

you will get this

```
    O1A1 | O2A1 |  Some other column values 
    O1A1 | O2A2 |  Some other column values 
    O1A1 | O2A3 |  Some other column values 
    O1A2 | O2A1 |  Some other column values 
    O1A2 | O2A2 |  Some other column values 
    O1A2 | O2A3 |  Some other column values
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your code, but it can be used for total 2 items in array. I need it dynamic which can work any (n) no of items into array.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, check this one, if it is helpful for you ...

```
<?php 
$input = array(
                0 => array(
                    'cid' => 'O1', 
                    'values' => array (0 => 'O1A1',1 => 'O1A2', 2=>'01A3',3=>'01A4')), 
                1 => array(
                    'cid' => 'O2', 
                    'values' => array (0 => 'O2A1', 1 => 'O2A2', 2=>'O2A3',3=>'O2A4',4=>'O2A5'))
             );

$matrixArr =array();

for( $i= 0; $i < count($input[0]['values']); $i++ ) 
{
    for( $j=0; $j < count($input[1]['values']); $j++ ) 
    {
        $matrixArr[$input[0]['values'][$i]][]= $input[1]['values'][$j];
    }
}

foreach($matrixArr as $key =>$val)
{
    foreach($val as $v)
    {
        echo $key." | ".$v.' |  Some other column values </br>';
    }
}
?>
```